# in Rstudio the encoding of characters change when closing the file tab

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, rstudio

I have a code with Persian characters, like ( س ) in it. 
when I save the file, I get a warning:
Not all of the characters could be encoded using ISO8859-1

when I close the file tab and reopen it again, the encodings have changed (turned into question marked). **BUT**,
if I close the Rstudio (**without closing the file tab**), in reopening, characters are fine and unchanged.

saving with other encodings like utf-8 code didn't help.

any idea why this is happening and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

save with encoding cp1256 and reopen with encoding (same cp1256) solved it